# Inserting data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is probably ridiculously easy for most of you, but I just started learning PHP and MySQL and I do not have a programming background so bear with me. I am trying to insert the following into a database.

Error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VARIABLE in
>   C:\wamp\www\coninsert.php on line 17

PHP code:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "algo","*****");
if (!$db)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("reno",$db);

$name=$_POST['nom'];
$address=$_POST['adresse'];
$city=$_POST['ville'];
$zip=$_POST['codepostal'];
$phone=$_POST['numtel'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$travaux=$_POST['travaux']

$sql = "INSERT INTO piste(name, address, ville, zip, phone, email, travaux) VALUES ("$name","$address","$city","$zip","$phone","$email","$travaux")";
mysql_query($sql)

mysql_close($db)
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: You should learn some [PHP 101: PHP For the Absolute Beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627).

Comment: Also, database connections should be created by a function or class defined in one script that's used in others. This way, DB credentials aren't scattered willy-nilly, which makes securing them easier. It also makes your DB connection code less vulnerable to typos. For a recent example on this site, see [PHP, Variable Scope Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769198/php-variable-scope-question/5769304#5769304). However, don't limit yourself to that one page; search the web for more.

Comment: I tried implementing scobal's answer and error changed to unexpected T_STRING. I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines:

```
$travaux=$_POST['travaux']
mysql_query($sql)
mysql_close($db)
```

You are missing semicolon.

---

Update .. aah yes, and there is the

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO piste(name, address, ville, zip, phone, email, travaux) 
        VALUES "$name","$address","$city","$zip","$phone","$email","$travaux")";
```

It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO piste(name, address, ville, zip, phone, email, travaux) 
        VALUES ('$name','$address','$city','$zip','$phone','$email','$travaux')";
```

And please, add some protection against SQL injections , because right not there is none.

---

Update2:

Lines like this: `$email=$_POST['email'];` 
Should look like: 
`$email= isset($_POST['email'])? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';`

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around text values:
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$zip."'....

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO piste(name, address, ville, zip, phone, email, travaux) VALUES ("$name","$address","$city","$zip","$phone","$email","$travaux")";
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO piste(name, address, ville, zip, phone, email, travaux) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $address . "','" . $city . "','" . $zip . "','" . $phone . "','" . $email . "','" . $travaux . "')";
```